# Xarray combine_by_coords return the monotonic global index error

Tags: python, gis, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to combine two spatial xarray datasets using combine_by_coords. These two datasets are two tiles next to each other. So there are overlapping coordinates. In the overlapping regions, the variable values of one of the datasets is nan.

I used the "combine_by_coords" with compat='no_conflicts' option. However, it returns the *monotonic global indexes along dimension y* error. It looks like it was an issue before but it was fixed ([here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/3150)). So I don't really know why I get this error. Here is an example (the netcdf tiles are [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Eon5yUiuhKCaDF0YK-l-S0JYGNN6eNg/view?usp=sharing)):

```
import xarray as xr

print(xr.__version__)
>>>0.15.1

ds1=xr.open_dataset('Tile1.nc')
ds2=xr.open_dataset('Tile2.nc')
ds = xr.combine_by_coords([ds1,ds2], compat='no_conflicts')
>>>...
 ValueError: Resulting object does not have monotonic global indexes along dimension y
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems like a bug to me. Inside `combine_by_coords`, indexes returned by [`_combine_nd`](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/f3ca63a4ac5c091a92085b477a0d34c08df88aa6/xarray/core/combine.py#L735) are effectively non-monotonic for your y coord, and I can't see why.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an alternative way (xarray or other packages) to do the same thing? I'll open an issue in xarray GitHub...

Comment: It works with `xr.merge([ds1, ds2])`, which makes the failure of `xr.combine_by_coords` even more suspiciours. Maybe you can open an issue.

Comment: I just opened an issue on xarray. The merging distorts the data. It changes the values, displaces the pixels and also leaves strips of nan values on the image.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This isn't a bug, it's throwing the error it should be throwing given your input. However I can see how the documentation doesn't make it very clear as to why this is happening!

`combine_by_coords` and `combine_nested` do two things: they concatenate (using `xr.concat`), and they merge (using `xr.merge`). `merge` groups variables of the same size, `concat` joins variables of different sizes onto the ends of one another. The concatenate step is never supposed to handle partially overlapping coordinates, and the `combine` functions therefore have the same restriction.

That error is an explicit rejection of the input you gave it: "you gave me overlapping coordinates, I don't know how to concatenate those, so I'll reject them." Normally this makes sense - when the overlapping coordinates aren't NaNs then it's ambiguous as to which values to choose.

In your case then you are asking it to perform a well-defined operation, and the discussion in the docs about merging overlapping coordinates [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/combining.html#merging-with-no-conflicts) implies that `compat='no_conflicts'` would handle this situation. Unfortunately that's only for `xr.merge`, not `xr.concat`, and so it doesn't apply for `combine_by_coords` either. This is definitely confusing.

It *might* be possible to generalise the `combine` functions to handle the scenario you're describing (where the overlapping parts of the coordinates are specified entirely by the non-NaN values). Please open an issue proposing this feature if you would like to see it.

(Issue [#3150](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/3150) was about something else, an actual bug in the handling of "coordinate dimensions which do not vary between each dataset".)

Instead, what you need to do is trim off the overlap first. That shouldn't be hard - presumably you know (or can determine) how big your overlap is, and all your NaNs are on one dataset. You just need to use the `.isel()` method with a slice. Once you've got rid of the overlapping NaNs then you should be able to combine it fine (and you shouldn't need to specify `compat` either). If you're using `combine_by_coords` as part of opening many files with `open_mfdataset` then it might be easier to write a trimming function which you apply first using the `preprocess` argument to `open_mfdataset`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Now it makes more sense.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a trimming function? In my case I have time data that overlaps (but both arrays are filled, I want to keep the last).

Comment: Your trimming function just accepts a dataset and returns a (trimmed) dataset. So you could literally use a lambda function like `preprocess=lambda ds: ds.isel(time=slice(0, -1))` for example